# Delay a method in UI thread without blocking it

Tags: java, android

How a can delay a method without blocking the UI thread? Say...

```
//this method is in the UI thread
public void doSomething() {
  myAsyncTask.execute() //its gona take like 1 or 2 sec, and keeps updating views in UI
  ... //i need to wait here for myAsyncTask finishes before the method finishes
}
```

Comment: You don't need to run such methods in the UI thread, you can run them in their own thread and when you have the result, then you can pass that to the UI

Comment: Is the onStop() method

Comment: already AsyncTAsk runs in background thread with code in doInBackground()

Comment: "i need to wait here for myAsyncTask finishes before the method finishes" -- sorry, that is not an option. Whatever work you want to do there should be part of the `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`. Note, though, that `AsyncTask` is deprecated.